# How to get User session in Login handling in Django?

Tags: django, session, authentication, django-views

I am learning Django. Well, more or less ;)
I am writing a login form. Because I want to learn how stuff works and because I need to do this.

I am not able to get things right. The user is, after authentication, not known in my "success" view as it seems, because it redirects back to the login.

I did set up my MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES.

"Funny thing" was that I thought it went well, because it seems to work. However, I figured out that was an old session with my user credentials. Now I deleted all session/cookie stuff and I it is not working.

This is what I have so far:

```
# views.py
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
from django.template import RequestContext

from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

def login(request):    
    username = password = usertype = login_error_message = ''
    if request.POST:
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        usertype = request.POST.get('usertype')

        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:         
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('login:success'))                                                             
            else:
                login_error_message = "Not active."
        else:
            login_error_message = "Unknown user"

    return render_response(request, 'login/login.html', {
        'login_error_message': login_error_message,
        'usertype': usertype
    })

def success(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():  
        user = request.user

        return render_response(request, 'login/success.html', {                                                        
            'username': user.username,                
        })
    else:        
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/login/')        

# https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/3/
# Wrapper simplifies using RequestContext in render_to_response.
# overkill at this point, but may come in handy in view files with more views
def render_response(req, *args, **kwargs):
    kwargs['context_instance'] = RequestContext(req)
    return render_to_response(*args, **kwargs)
```

And this are my url's:

```
# urls.py
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from diataal.apps.login import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',            
    url(r'^$', views.login),
    url(r'^success/', views.success, name='success'),
)
```

My url shows the login page. If I do not add the check on the user in the "success" view, the success page is shown (a 302 response from login and then a 200 response from the success page); that seems ok to me.

But with the check, I get a 302 response from the "success" view and I am back at the login page again...

I have no clue how to solve this... What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `login` view, you only `authenticate` the user. You do not **actually** login the user.

[`authenticate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.authenticate) only takes the username and password and returns a `user` object if the credentials are valid. This is a pre-cursor to the actual [`login` call](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.login)